# How to remove child element from bsondocument using name?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the following document loaded as `BsonDocument`

```
{
    "_id" : 903692860,
    "url" : "",    
    "evaluationContext" : {
        "startTime" : ISODate("2019-08-26T19:22:02.442Z"),
        "endTime" : ISODate("2019-08-26T19:22:02.442Z"),
        "markersData" : null,
        "markersData_con" : 0
    }
}
```

I want to remove `markersData` and `markersData_con` property from `BsonDocument`

i tried ( assume `doc` is an instance of BsonDocument)

```
doc.Remove("evaluationContext.markersData");
doc.Remove("evaluationContext.markersData_con");
```

but its not working

Comment: Did you try UnSet?

Comment: BsonDocument does not have `UnSet` method

Comment: Try your query in string and pass it to Bson serializer that convert it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var evaluationContext = doc["evaluationContext"].AsBsonDocument;
evaluationContext.remove("markersData");
evaluationContext.remove("markersData_con");
```

Answer (score 0):

I could delete that element with the following code:

```
public async Task Remove(ObjectId id)
{
    var context = new Context();
    var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", id);
    var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update
        .Unset("evaluationContext.markersData_con");
    await context.MyCollection.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(filter, update);
}
```

Comment: i dont want to remove it from the database. I want to remove the property from the retrieved document